# How to set crystal report's textbox value at run time?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

How to set crystal report's textbox value at run time. I have a textbox in section2 (page header) in crystal report, now I have to set Text property of this textbox at run time. Basically I have to pass user name in this textbox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change textbox text in runtime. You can use this:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

rptMyReport report = new rptMyReport();
TextObject to = (TextObject)report.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section2"].ReportObjects["textboxname"];
to.Text = newvalue;
```

The another way is to use parameters.

Comment: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine namespace.

Comment: You need to addreference, it is located in my case in folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll if you dont have it alredy in GAC

Comment: Great :) This way you can change every object on report at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the user name before the report opens you can add a parameter field (string) to the report and then put that field on the report where you want it to appear at runtime. You will just need to pass it into the report as a parameter just like you would any other parameter.

```
    Dim UserName As String = "BukHix" 
    crDOC.SetParameterValue("UserName", UserName)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
((TextObject)rpt.Section2.ReportObjects["Textbox"]).Text = "yourvalue";
```

Comment: Its simply great, without ReportDefinition.

Comment: where should it be done? On form which is hosting Report Viewer?